# Other users still have a connection to me after socket.leave

Tags: node.js, socket.io

For a fact, as a user, I lose room connection when I do socket.leave(roomname). But it feels like other users may still have a connection to me after I should I have left the room.

```
io.on('connect',onConnect);

function onConnect(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('room',(room)=>{
        socket.join(room);
        console.log('user joined in this room '+room);

    });

    socket.on('message',(message)=>{
        io.sockets.in(message.room).emit(message.room,message.message);
        console.log(message)

    });

    socket.on('leaveRoom',(message)=>{
        socket.leave(message.room);
        console.log(message.message);
    });
}
```

I had a simulation running on my computer and the actually application running on my phone. That's how I noticed that even when I left a room, I was still being sent messages. I've searched and a lot of people are doing it this way.

Thank for those looking at this. If there is a better approach, please let me know.

Comment: Have you verified in `socket.join(room); ` `room` and `socket.leave(message.room);` `message.room` both are equal just console and check may be you find issue there. ?

Comment: @ShivamMishra I verified it and re-verified it along with the type I'm dealing with and they're both the same. Even compare them with the == Boolean operation